# I'm looking for the word that means opposition towards a specific nation or country

Tags: single-word-requests

Essentially, I'm looking for a word that means the opposite of nationalism. Whereas nationalism means support for a nation's interests, the word I'm looking for means opposition to a certain nation's interests.

Does such a word exist?

I found anti-nationalism, but that means opposition to nationalism as a concept, and also xenophobia, but that means opposition to any nation other than your own. What I'm looking for is opposition to a single specific nation; essentially a hypernym for conc

Comment: You **must** give a sentence that will show how you intend to use the word. Could you do that, please?

Comment: What’s wrong with *anti-[country]*.  anti-Russia, anti-US, anti-China...

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a specific word, but you can prefix a country's name with "anti" to indicate opposition to the country in general. For example:

> He is anti-Russia or anti-Russian

indicates that he is opposed to the country, its government, its ideals, its actions, etc.